# Cocoa App NSOutlineView is not populated in Mac OS 10.10

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, osx-yosemite

My Cocoa app has a NSOutlineVew which is populated with data read from a text file and it's basically static and loaded only once in the beginning.

Prior to 10.10, the NSOutlineView works and user can drag and drop item from it to a NSTableView. However, if we run the app in 10.10, the NSOutlineView is not populated with the data and basically is just empty. There is no error message in the console log. Basically, what we found out is that the following codes are not executed in 10.10.

```
#pragma OutlineView for CmdSet
// Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? [cmdTree count] : [item numberOfChildren];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? YES : [item isExpandable];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? [cmdTree objectAtIndex:index] : [[item children]   objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
return [item nodeName];
}
```

My app basically is written with AppController and I attach the code and screenshots for your reference.

```
@interface AppController : NSObject {
    ...
 IBOutlet NSOutlineView *outlineViewCmdSet;
}
```

Can anyone point me to the correct direction how I can solve this to be able to run in both 10.10 and the prior versions? Our clients are using different Mac OS. It's good to be able to support all of the OSes.

The OutLine View in Interface Builder
[image: OutLine View in Interface Builder]

Comment: You data source methods are not getting called. Is the delegate set, is it a cell based view is anything nil?

Comment: I may not understand your question clearly. Yes, i have linked the cell based view's Data Source to AppController. For "Is the delegate set", i am unsure. How can I check?